# Calculating the Shared Variance from a Correlation Coefficient?

Tags: correlation, variance, r-squared

We often square coefficients like the R coefficient in simple/multiple linear regression or standardized factor loadings to get a percentage of variance accounted for by predictor variables.

Can the same principle be applied to a Pearson correlation coefficient? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#As_squared_correlation_coefficient) suggests that

> When an intercept is included, then r2 is simply the square of the
>   sample correlation coefficient (i.e., r) between the observed outcomes
>   and the observed predictor values

But in a simple Pearson correlation coefficient, intercepts are not included. So is squaring still appropriate to determine the percent of shared variance between variables?

Comment: You can always square a correlation $r$ (between $x$ and $y$, say) and the result is equal to the $r^2$ or $R^2$ (notation varies, but for two variables the difference is unimportant) you would get if you did either regression, $y$ on $x$ or $x$ on $y$. But _shared variance_ is not good wording: $y$ and $x$ will have often have quite different units and so their variances won't be comparable at all. Rather, $r^2$ or $R^2$ is the fraction of the variance of either variable associated with (or "explained by", although many dislike such expressions) regression on the other.

Comment: Otherwise put, every correlation implies two regressions, each with an intercept. Whether you carry out either regression is another matter.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood Wikipedia. The Pearson correlation removes mean from dependent and independent variables(centers).in a regression model with non centred dependent and independent variables you need intercept term. Put another way you need intercept for uncentred data, the Pearson correlation centres the data

Comment: Wow - all brilliant and enlightening comments. Many thanks. I'm just wondering why neither of you 'answered' the question.